# Framework for a text game: using DIV and LI

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using CSS & Javascript to make the framework for a text game.

I'm trying to make a (div or li, or it can be anything else as long as it's as ideal as possible) which can make text appear in another div. I'm also not sure about using ID or classes for a few things.

I know this sounds very vague! Run my jsfiddle to see exactly what I'm trying to do, you'll see immediately what I try to do. How would you do this?  --> http://jsfiddle.net/45z8xntk/3

Thank you ;)

```
<body>
<div id='everything'>
    <div id='rooms'>
        <ul id='house'>
            <li id='living'>Living Room</li>
            <li id='kitchen'>Kitchen</li>
            <li id='bathroom'>Bathroom</li>
            <li id='bedroom'>Bedroom</li>
            <li id='extra'>Extra Room</li>
            <li id='balcony'>Balcony
                <br></br>Visit rooms, click on a room and the room description shows in the light blue div. HOW TO DO THIS?</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='big'>
        <div id='story'>
            <ul id='storylist'>
                <li>
                    <br>Story Line (main game screen)</br>This is where the story is told.
                    <br>Messages like "you picked up a hammer"</br>"You try the door but it's locked", dialogue, etc.
                    <br>The story progresses here. No interactivity in this part.</br>My idea is to just add li's with javascript here.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='descr'>When you enter a room, the description shows here. The description of the room is sometimes different, it depends on story progress. How to make room descriptions flexible for the same room? You can click on items here, making them unclickable the second time, and they'll go to the inventory.
            <BR></BR>WHAT SYSTEM is best for items? Item=div, items are li, or...??
            <ul id='dliving'>
                <li id='living1'>You are in the living room 1</li>
                <li id='living2'>Living room 2</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id='dkitchen'>
                <li id=kitchen1>kitchen 1</li>
                <li id=kitchen2>kitchen 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='choice'>
            <ul>
                <li>Go outside > here you click on choices > goes to the red story line ^</li>
                <li>Stay inside > your choices affect the story outcome. Very easy once I know how to make stuff appear in the red div</li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='inventory'>Inventory: if you're in the right room to use the item, the item disappears and what happens shows up in the main story line (red). If you can't use the item in that room, a general "nothing happens" message is shown in the red div
            <div id='invmove'>
                <div id=item1>Knife</div>
                <div id=item2>Soap</div>
                <div id=item3>Fork</div>
                <div id=item4>Mouse Burger</div>
                <div id=item5></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#everything {
margin-top:1%;
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
margin-bottom:1%;
background-color:lightgreen;
font-size:1em;
padding:10px;
}
ul {
list-style:none;
}
#house {
background-color:pink;
}
#house li {
margin-right:40px;
display:inline;
}
#story {
height:200px;
overflow:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
background-color:red;
}
#descr {
height:130px;
background-color:lightblue;
}
/*hmmm... how?*/
 #living1, #living2, #kitchen1, #kitchen2 {
display:none;
}
#choice {
height:80px;
background-color:yellow;
}
#inventory {
height:100px;
padding-top:20px;
padding-left:20px;
background-color:purple;
}
#inventory div div {
display:inline-block;
background-color:lightblue;
}
#invmove {
display:inline;
margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: i would push all your state into attribs on the body, and then you can use just CSS to show different content depending on the situation. for example, you can have <div id=room><span class=normal>blah</span></span class=weak>danger blah</span></div>. then, in css, body[data-weak=true] #room .weak{display:block;}body[data-weak=true] #room span:not(.weak){display:none;}   use document.body.dataset.weak=true; to set that state and thus toggle the CSS. in short, this css approach can make many independent or mutual conditions take effect without any IFs, ANDs, or ELSEs...

Comment: But, CSS doesn't really dynamic pages, does it? Something like adding/removing classes.

How would I do this:

    <div>
    Click here
    </div>
    <div>
    To make something appear here
    </div>

Comment: if you use a little bit of js to apply the attribs, then the heavy lifting is done in css instead of JS, which is usually easier to understand, maintain, and customize.